# Softmax Returns Identity Matrix

Tags: tensorflow, softmax

My input to `softmax`,  `y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W) + b)`, is a valued matrix

```
tf.matmul(x, W) + b =
[[  9.77206726e+02]
 [  5.72391296e+02]
 [  3.53560760e+02]
 [  4.75727379e-01]
 [  6.58911804e+02]]
```

But when this is inputted into `softmax`, I get:

```
tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W) + b) =
[[ 1.]
 [ 1.]
 [ 1.]
 [ 1.]
 [ 1.]]
```

Causing the output of my training to be an array of `1`s, which means none of the weights `W` or biases `b` update on each batch of training data.  This also causes my accuracy to be `1` on a random set of test data

Below is my code:

```
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 2])

W = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([2, 1]))

b = tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([1]))

y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W) + b)

## placeholder for cross-entropy
y_ = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, [None, 1])

## cross-entropy function
cross_entropy = tf.reduce_mean(-tf.reduce_sum(y_ * tf.log(y), reduction_indices=[1]))

## backpropagation & gradienct descent
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(cross_entropy)

## initialize variables
init = tf.initialize_all_variables()

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(init)

ITER_RANGE = 10
EVAL_BATCH_SIZE = ( len(training_outputs)/ITER_RANGE )
training_outputs = np.reshape(training_outputs, (300, 1))
## training
for i in range(ITER_RANGE):
  print 'iterator:'
  print i

  ## batch out training data
  BEGIN = ( i*EVAL_BATCH_SIZE )
  END = ( (i*EVAL_BATCH_SIZE) + EVAL_BATCH_SIZE )

  batch_ys = training_outputs[BEGIN:END]
  batch_xs = training_inputs[BEGIN:END]

  print 'batch_xs'
  print batch_xs

  print 'batch_ys'
  print batch_ys

  sess.run(train_step, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})

  # y = tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W) + b)
  print 'y'
  print (sess.run(y, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys}))

  #print 'x'
  #print sess.run(x)

  print 'W'
  print sess.run(W)

  print 'b'
  print sess.run(b)

  print 'tf.matmul(x, W) + b'
  print sess.run(tf.matmul(x, W) + b, feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})

  print 'tf.nn.softmaxtf.matmul(x, W) + b)'
  print sess.run((tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W) + b)), feed_dict={x: batch_xs, y_: batch_ys})

correct_prediction = tf.equal(tf.argmax(y,1), tf.argmax(y_,1))

accuracy = tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(correct_prediction, tf.float32))

test_outputs = np.random.rand(300, 1)

## the following prints 1
print(sess.run(accuracy, feed_dict={x: test_inputs, y_: test_outputs}))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the definition of [Softmax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Softmax_function), it "'squashes' a K-dimensional vector of arbitrary real values to a K-dimensional vector of real values in the range (0, 1) *that add up to 1*"

If there is only 1 output value, then the Categorical Probability Distribution that Softmax outputs is just `1`, as opposed to values that add up to 1.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your softmax function is applied to every distinct value in the output vector. Try to transpose your output, i.e. change `tf.nn.softmax(tf.matmul(x, W) + b))` to `tf.nn.softmax(tf.transpose(tf.matmul(x, W) + b)))`.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you only have two classes {yes, no} and `tf.matmul(x, W) + b` represents the probablity of {yes}. In this case, you should use `tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits` instead of `softmax`. Something like:

```
y_pred = tf.matmul(x, W) + b
loss = tf.reduce_sum(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(y_pred, y_))
train_step = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(loss)
```

Answer (score 0):

The cross entropy loss is incomplete. Use cross entropy with logits.